# How to enter Unicode (or other) symbols in LaTeX within Keynote (iWork)

Tags: pages, font, keynote, iwork, latex

In Keynote and other iWork apps, it is possible to enter formulas (and text) in LaTeX. This is an immensely valuable feature. But...

- How can I enter an astronomical (or other) symbol, via Unicode or by other means, *directly* in a LaTeX formula (ie. *without copying and pasting from the Character Viewer* — which doesn’t work anyway directly in the LaTeX formula editor within Keynote)?

  - For example, I wish to get the Mars symbol ♂ or the Venus symbol ♀ by entering `\mars` or `\venus`.

[This Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501) claims that one can also enter (ASCII) Unicode characters, but no indication is given there, in the blahtex documentation, or anywhere else about how to enter a Unicode character.

I’d also be happy with any non-Unicode route that allows me to enter such characters directly within the LaTeX coding within Keynote. Any approach by which I could use any of the astronomical symbols in the [LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) would be a dream.

Comment: Does this work?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/how-do-i-enter-an-arbitrary-unicode-code-point-into-my-document

Comment: Sadly, it does not, but it was worth a try! I’ve now tried all combo’s of: 
`\symbol{MYVAR}` where `MYVAR` was `“2642`, `’2642`, `&#x2642`; etc. (also with UTF-8: `E29982EFB88E`)

Comment: How about typing directly using the Unicode hex input source.  Hold down option and type 2642..  might need to be in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tip from [tom-gewecke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49804/tom-gewecke), I have a functioning workaround.

- First, you have to enable the *Unicode Hex Input* keyboard in your *System Preferences* > *Keyboard* > *Input Sources*.
- Then, of course, you activate it, for example, by ticking *Show Input menu in menu bar*, then selecting *Unicode Hex Input* with your cursor in the menu bar.
- Once this keyboard is enabled, you can enter Unicode characters by holding down the Alt/Option key ⌥ on your keyboard and, while holding it down, typing the code for the Unicode character.
- You can find code for Unicode characters by, for example, from the same keyboard menu bar item, selecting *Show Emoji & Symbols*, which opens the *Character Viewer*.

That much was known. The workaround to get a Unicode character directly into a LaTeX formula with an iWork application (eg. Keynote, Pages) is:

- Once you open the editor for equations ( *Insert* > *Equation...* or ⌥⌘E ) to enter LaTeX code, you type `\text{ }`, and when your cursor is between those brackets in the text field, you type the code for the Unicode character as described above.
- Et voila, you have any Unicode character directly in your formula. For example:

  - `\text{⌥2642}` produces ♂
  - `\vec{R}_\text{⌥2642}` produces [image: vector R with subscript MarsSymbol]

Comment: To  type a Character whose unicode number has more than 4 digits, you hold down option while typing the 8 hex numbers of the character's utf16 value.